# Python subprocess.Popen: not accepting a string with spaces but only when there are two strings

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

subprocess.Popen accepts this string and starts the tcl shell process:

```
'"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\TCL\\bin\\tclsh.exe "'
```

If you can just see, I have encapsulated the string in double quotes.  Now, when I try to give an argument to the tcl shell (which is essential because I am running tcl scripts), I get a surprising problem.  For instance, When I pass this string to Popen:

```
""C:\\Program\\ Files\\ (x86)\\Tcl\\bin\\tclsh.exe " "C:/Users//Has Space//TestingTCLComms.tcl""
```

I get the following error:

```
"'C:\\Program\\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
 operable program or batch file.\r\n"
```

The Following executes properly on the command line:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Tcl\bin\tclsh.exe " "C:/Users/Has Space/TestingTCLComms.tcl"
```

Comment: try to pass `r"C:\Program Files (x86)\TCL\bin\tclsh.exe"` with this prefix `r` to indicate that this is a [literal string](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/strings.html)

Comment: so, the string r"C:\Program Files (x86)\TCL\bin\tclsh.exe" does properly run the tcl shell when passed to Popen.  However, once I add an argument as in str: r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Tcl\bin\tclsh.exe " + "C:/Users/noSpace/TestingTCLComms.tcl", I get the same problem C:\Program\ not recognized.

Comment: then, pass `shell=True` in the `Popen` call, like: `Popen(your_string, shell=True)`, but without breaking the string... just write as if you were in the shell prompt, with all the arguments ans so on...

Comment: Everything is already being passed shell=True.

Comment: interesting.  I set shell=False and it seems to work now.  We may have an answer here.

Comment: Do the rules in http://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#converting-argument-sequence explain this behavior?